# Need to get the specific value using key in json object

Tags: jquery, json

I have encoded a json object as

```
 Object { thumb0: "https://gourmet.itulstaging.com/store/image/cache/catalog/SRIRACHAMANGOBALSAMIC_FINAL_2x3-280x370.jpg", id0: "176", thumb1: "https://gourmet.itulstaging.com/store/image/cache/catalog/BLACKCHERRYBALSAMIC_FINAL-280x370.jpg", id1: "143"..}.
```

I have taken each value using **jQuery.each**. The key value pair is getting as shown below. I need to get the thumb value only from this. Because of I need to append this image path using append. Now I got the id too.

```
jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
     console.log(key+" "+val);               
     jQuery('#imagenn').append('<div class="item"> <div class="col-xs-2"> <img src="' + val+ '" /> </div></div>');
                       
    });

thumb0 https://gourmet.it.com/image/SRIRACHAMANGOBALSAMIC_FINAL_2x3-280x370.jpg 
id0 176 
thumb1 https://gourmet.it.com/image/BLACKCHERRYBALSAMIC_FINAL-280x370.jpg 
id1 143
```

I need **thumb0** to append in **src** and **id0** as a tag and need to continue other iteration as **thumb1** in **src** and **id1** in a tag.
Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correct but why don't you just add a if clause to your loop?

```
let lastThumb = null;
jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) 
{
    console.log(key+" "+val);  
    if(key.substr(0,5) === 'thumb')
        lastThumb = val;
    else if(key.substr(0, 2) === 'id')
        /* insert id val + lastThumb here */
});
```

Comment: i have added the code but not working as expected. i need to take each thumb and id in one loop to append jQuery('#imagenn').append('<div class="item"> <div class="col-xs-2"> <a href="something/ID "><img src="' + EACHTHUMBVALUE+ '" /></a> </div></div>');

Comment: can i take id along with that without using other if loop